# Trying to make a personalized greeting with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, session-storage

Well for the website I made a little script that when you load the site there is a prompt that asks for your name, and when you submit it, it displays a hello message in the header.

The problem is that when you go to the different pages of the website the script executes again and ask for the name again. For instance, you go from home to the contact section and when the contact section loads, the prompt appears again. I want that to execute once and display the information throughout the entire website. Here is the JS Code:

```js
var nombre = sessionStorage.setItem[prompt("Bienvenido a Plantas All the Time, ingrese su nombre:")]

var login = sessionStorage.getItem(nombre);

if (nombre == "") { 
  prompt("Bienvenido a Plantas All The Time, ingrese su nombre:")

} else {
  document.getElementById('usuario').innerHTML = "<h4> Hola, " + nombre + "</h4>";

}
```

Whenever I execute this the prompt appears I enter the name and it prints "undefined".

Comment: `setItem` is a method and so the parameter you pass should be in parenthesis, not brackets. For example `var nobre = sessionStorage.setItem(prompt(.....))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many tiny mistakes here.

- `setItem` takes as parameter a key and a value, while `getItem` takes the key (as string); think of the sessionStore as a dictionary/map; You thus need to give the name you store a key, e.g. `"name-key"`;
- in the logic, you shouldn't call `setItem` every time you load the page, but only if the user hasn't already provided one;

The idea is thus to first check the storage, then if no name is set, ask the user for one.

Here is a working example:

```
var key = "name-key"; // key used to store the name in the sessionStorage

// first, try to retrieve the name
var name = sessionStorage.getItem(key);

if(!name){ // if no name has been provided yet
  // ask the user, and keep asking until it enters a value
  while (!name) {
    name = prompt("Bienvenido a Plantas All The Time, ingrese su nombre:");
  }
  // store the name in storage, so next time no prompt will be necessary
  sessionStorage.setItem(key, name);
}

// at this point, name is set, so you can great your user
document.getElementById('usuario').innerHTML = "<h4> Hola, " + name + "</h4>";
```

Comment: @mbojko good catch, got confused with the `nombre` here (number in french), thanks for the edit !

Comment: Thanks guys!! for some reason its not working, the prompt is not shown and it only prints null